# Is there any TFTP client for iPhone sdk, which can tranfer files to TFTP server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tftp

Is it possible to use a normal FTP client (FTP operations using the NSURLConnection and CFFTPStream APIs) to send file to TFTP server, for iOS?

Or is there a dedicated TFTP client for iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the library from this link http://sourceforge.net/projects/tftp/

and then you can create your own custom library and use it according to your requirement.